# php mPdf page-break-inside: auto not work

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

When I generate the table in the pdf file, and when `tr` contains long text, page breaks, and the next cell of the table is transferred to the next page. I tried to use style:

```
 table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfoot {
     page-break-inside: auto !important;
}
```

but it's not working. How to enable page break inside ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Forcing the break or avoiding it?

Comment: @ Finwe , Me need disable `page-break-inside: avoid` from `tr`, when `tr `has long text. Forcing the break.

Comment: This is not supported in current mPDF version. avoid is the only possible value;

Comment: Thx, its very bad ((

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/resizing.html

Comment: Yes, but its not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139757/mpdf-page-break-based-on-element-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert line:

```
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
```

and use

```
page-break-inside: avoid
```

in table tag

Comment: Valuable answer. Thanks man. can we use `page-break-inside` for **tbody,thead,tfoot**

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
table {page-break-inside: avoid;}
```